# Why reference to a non-shared member of a Windows Form is allowed?

Tags: .net, vb.net

We came across this during problem determination within our code. We've fixed the bug, but the question remains:

Why is a reference to a non-shared member of a "Windows Form" allowed?

In order to replicate behaviour, create new Windows Forms application (I'm using VS2012, .net4.0), populate default form, Form1.vb, with:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1

    Private _private As String

    Public ReadOnly Property NotSharedProperty As String
        Get
            Return _private
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then add a new class and call it PropertClass, fill it with:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class ProperClass

    Private _private As String

    Public ReadOnly Property NotSharedProperty As String
        Get
            Return _private
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then add another class, call it ExampleClass and fill it:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class ExampleClass

    Public Sub New()

        If Form1.NotSharedProperty Is Nothing Then
            '.....................
        End If

        If ProperClass.NotSharedProperty Is Nothing Then
            '.....................
        End If


    End Sub

End Class
```

In the ExampleClass, `ProperClass.NotSharedProperty` gives me "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." as one would expect. `Form1.NotSharedProperty` does not. Why?

Comment: `Form1.NotSharedProperty` is using the default form instance that VB creates when you dont peoperly instance your forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the many Visual Basic.NET compatibility features.

When you refer to a form by its type in old-school Visual Basic, you get the reference to a *default instance* of that form. That's just how VB development was done in the past (and VB wasn't the only environment that used this convention). Most of the time, you really only had one instance of each form.

Since you're not exploiting this feature on purpose, you probably never actually used the default instance, and your create your own instances as needed instead. In that case, `Form1.NotSharedProperty` will simply return whatever the default is.

Comment: I think it's important to point out that most experienced VB.NET developers really frown on using default instances.   They tend to introduce a lot of hard to diagnose errors. You should avoid them.

Comment: It was quite difficult to pin down the bug in our case. The bug was simply, that without much thought we've tried accessing property as it was a shared property rather than getting property of instantiated form object which was what we meant. IDE did not complain, so bug was not spotted leading to some quite bizzare behaviour. Accepting answer.

Comment: @parvee Yeah, it's a bit annoying that you can't turn the feature off. The only way of "disabling" default instances in VB.NET I know of is to remove the paremeter-less constructor (usually, you'd add a static "constructor" method instead, while keeping the constructor itself private or protected). In practice, I've rarely had to do this on purpose since I usually pass dependencies explicitly, so I don't tend to have forms that have a public parameter-less constructor in the first place.